# Why does a stationary mirror reflect different imagery depending on observer's angle?

Tags: reflection

I'm a scientifically uneducated buffoon with little schooling, who has just been reading about the simulation hypothesis and now can't work out something that should be straightforward.

I'm lying on a couch (with my mind now blown from simulation theories), wondering why the image I can see in a mirror is not the mirror image of what is directly in front of it.  Why does my eye's angle (down to the left), reflect back what is up to the right? If I stand directly in front of the mirror, I get a reflection of me and a couple of doors.  Why don't I still see the doors reflected when I'm lying on the couch?  I.e. Why does my eye determine what's reflected?  This is a genuine question from a genuinely academically challenged individual.  Thank you.

Comment: These might help: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-1/The-Law-of-Reflection and https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/25-2-the-law-of-reflection

Comment: Thank you these links, the explanations were really helpful and solved my question very well indeed.  However, now I'm struggling with idea that one flat mirror surface will 'display' multiple images (variations of views) to multiple observers at the same time.  I don't really understand what I mean myself now :)  This is a good thing though.  I am going to carry out some research in my spare time.